# ¿Cómo oculto objetos en un IF dentro de un bucle FOR en Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente, problematica, tengo que hacer una comparación de un if dentro de un blucle for. El problema? Es con datos de una base de datos y debo hacer que unos botones aparezcan o no, cuando coloque el if dentro del for, el código simplemente me tiraba un error diciendo de que no conocia las ids de los botones y si lo coloco afuera solo agarra la primera columna y no valida el resto

Alguna idea si eso se puede hacer?

Este es mi codigo, el problema empieza justo cuando corre el for. No se como ocultar los botones dentro del ciclo for porque porque tira un error diciendo de que los botones no existen

```
function buscarAgendaUsuario(){
                var isChecked = document.getElementById('tResultados').checked;
                if(isChecked){
                    Resultados = 1;
                }else{
                    Resultados = 0;
                }
                datos = { 
                    "opcion"  : "buscarAgenda",
                    "id_usuario": $('#Id_usuario').val(),
                    "resultado":Resultados,
                    "fecha_inicio":$('#Fecha_inicio').val(),
                    "fecha_fin":$('#Fecha_fin').val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url:'../controllers/perfilClienteController.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: datos
                }).done(function(response){
                    var data = JSON.parse(response).respuesta;
                    var msj = JSON.parse(response).msj;
                    var success = JSON.parse(response).success; 
                    html=`
                    <table 
                    class="table table-bordered table-hover" 
                    id="lista">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>Dia</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Fecha</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Hora</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Clase</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Instructor</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Sede</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Sala</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>Opciones</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>`;
                    if(success){
                        var valores = eval(data);
                        for(i=0;i<valores.length;i++){
                            html+=`
                            <tr>
                                <input type="hidden" id="hora_termino" value="${valores[i]['hora_fin']}"></input>
                                <input type="hidden" id="hora_inicio" value="${valores[i]['hora_inicio']}"></input>
                                <td>${valores[i][0]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][1]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][2]}-${valores[i][3]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][4]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][5]} ${valores[i][6]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][7]}</td>
                                <td>${valores[i][8]}</td>
                                <td><a id="emitir" target="_blank" href="${valores[i]['url_emision']}">
                                <input id="url_emision" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" value="IR A CLASE"></a>
                                <a id="grabada" target="_blank" href="${valores[i]['url_grabada']}">
                                <input id="url_grabada" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="CLASE GRABADA"></a>
                                <button id="calificar" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">CALIFICAR</button>
                                <button id="cancelar" class="btn btn-outline-warning"
                                onclick="cancelacionAgenda(${valores[i]['id_clasecliente']})">
                                CANCELAR CLASE
                                </button></td>
                            </tr>`;
                    var hora_inicio = [valores[i]['hora_inicio']];
                    hora_inicio.slice(start, end)
                    html+="</tbody></table>"
                    $("#lista").html(html);
                    var today = new Date();
                    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
                    var outString = hora_inicio.replace(/[:~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
                    var hora1 = parseInt(outString); 
                    console.log(hora1);
                    var outString2 = time.replace(/[:~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
                    var hora2 = parseInt(outString2); 
                    console.log(hora2);

                        if(hora2 < hora1){
                        document.getElementById("cancelar").style.display = "true";
                        document.getElementById("grabada").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("calificar").style.display = "none";
                        console.log("Pequeño");
                            }else{ //Si la hora actual es superior a la hora que termina, cambia el boton
                        document.getElementById("url_emision").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("cancelar").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("calificar").style.display = "true";
                        document.getElementById("grabada").style.display = "true";
                        console.log("Grande");
                    }
                    }
                }else{
                    html+=`
                    <tr><td colspan="7">${msj}</td></tr></tbody></table>`;
                    $("#lista").html(html);
                }     
            });
        }

        //funcion de cancelacion para los clientes de la clase, no funciona la parte de la hora
        function cancelacionAgenda(
            id_clasecliente = $("#id_clasecliente").val()){

            event.preventDefault();
                    
            datos = { 
                "opcion":"cancelacionAgenda",
                id_clasecliente
            };
                    
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '../controllers/clasesController.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: datos
                        
            }).done(function(data){
                var success = JSON.parse(data).success;
                var msj = JSON.parse(data).msj;
            
                if(success){
                    swal("¡Realizado!", msj, "success").then((value) => {
                        location.reload();
                        //swal("¡Se ha cancelado su clase!", msj, "error");
                    });
                }else{
                    swal("¡Error!", msj, "error");
                }
                        
            });               
        }
        </script>
    {/literal}
{/block}
```

EDIT: Añadi una forma de comprar las fechas volviendo a todos los valores, int

Comment: ¿Por qué o para qué usas `eval()`? ¿Dónde está el if que te ocasiona problemas? Si estás armando el HTML es lógico que los elementos todavía no existan en el DOM. Deberías cortar la cadena y agregar u omitir los elementos que correspondan.

Comment: El if que causa problemas es el if(time <= hora_termino && time < hora_inicio){

Comment: Triby, alguna idea de que se podría hacer?

Comment: Para empezar, `hora_inicio` y `hora_termino` no parecen ser cadenas que puedan convertirse a objeto `Date`, deberían incluir la fecha para facilitar las comparaciones. Si corriges esa parte creo que puedo ayudar.

Comment: Realmente tu problema es que intentas darle eventos o modificar atributos a elementos que aun no existen en tu DOM. primero debes crearlos, después de eso si ajustar los atributos de tus elementos según desees

Answer (score 0):

*Veo que intentas modificar los atributos de tus elementos, pero como aun no existen en el DOM esto no es posible, te comparto un ejemplo de como puedes realizar lo que deseas.*

```js
function cargarElementos() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
  var buttons = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    buttons += '<button id="btn-' + i + '" style="display: none;">Boton ' + (i + 1) + '</button>';

    if (i === 3) {
      /**
        Aqui agregamos nuestros elementos al DOM
      */
      $("#lista").html(buttons);

      // Después de agregar los elementos en el DOM, les asignamos los estilos que deseamos.
      atributosButtons();
    }
  }
}

function atributosButtons() {
  var buttons = $("#lista").children();
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.style.display = 'flex';
    button.style.border = '1px solid transparent';
    button.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    button.style.margin = '3px';
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      button.style.color = '#fff';
      button.style.backgroundColor = '#0095ff';
      button.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4)';

    } else {
      button.style.color = '#39739d';
      button.style.backgroundColor = '#e1ecf4';
      button.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.7)';
      button.style.borderColor = '#7aa7c7';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body onload="cargarElementos()">
  <div id="lista"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

*Espero te sirva*